# query to update post with featured images from array

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have 100 existing posts of a custom post type that I need to update their featured images... How would I go about creating a query to randomly update these images from an array of say 20 images from the media library?

Any pointers would be great, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add random featured images to post that currently don't have a featured image?

Comment: Hi Tomas, each post already has a featured image that I'd like to change to a new, randomly selected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudo-code answer.

1. First get the posts you want with `get_posts` (you can pass the
   post_type as an argument)
2. Then get the ID of the images you want to set as thumnbail
3. Now do a loop and try with a query similar to this one:

   "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = $image_id WHERE post_id = $post_id AND meta_key = ''_thumbnail_id''"

NOTE: To get the $image_id from the array of key you could use `array_rand`. You are gonna need `wpdb` to run the query.

Read the docs, and ask a question if you have any doubts.